Why is equation label not working in MathJax?
I had this MathJax code for equations working:
\begin{align}
p_i &= p_f cos \theta+p cos \beta \ \ \ (x-component) \tag{2''} \\
0 &= p_f sin \theta + p sin \beta \ \ \ (y-component)\tag{3''}
\end{align}


But when I added \label's as shown below:
\begin{align}
p_i &= p_f cos \theta+p cos \beta \ \ \ (x-component) \tag{2''} \label{eq2}\\
0 &= p_f sin \theta + p sin \beta \ \ \ (y-component)\tag{3''}\label{eq3}
\end{align}

It stopped working? I thought it used to be working.
